# Firestore fields null type usage

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of groups, each group document has a map of admins. I store admins ids as keys of the map and for the values, I use the null type. So, when I want to retrieve this map, what is the java type to use, since null is not type in java, It's more of a value. I mean I can not have a variable of type null in java. So, How should my map look like :

```
HashMap<String, ?what-type> map = new HashMap();
```

What is that ?what-type ?

Comment: Why do you want to store the 'admins' as Map? since you want to store 'admins' as ids, you can simply use a list right? or do you have any other use case?

Comment: If you really need to store it as a map, you can use "Object" as the value type in hashmap

Comment: I store as a map because I might want to get the list of groups that a user manages and since map fields are indexed just like other document fields, I could perform a firestore query to get that list easily. Can I do this with firestore lists ? Are they indexed, too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if `null` is a [supported data-type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) in Cloud Firestore, don't store `null` as values, rather store a boolean value, for example, `true`. In this way, the type of the object you were looking for is Boolean. So now you can use:

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap();
```

However, a more appropriate solution would be to use:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
```

As you don't always know the type of the value. So setting that as an Object might be more helpful in this case. Please note, that an object can also have the value of `null`, so this solution will cover all situations.

Comment: I store as a map because I might want to get the list of groups that a user manages and since map fields are indexed just like other document fields, I could perform a firestore query to get that list easily. Can I do this with firestore lists ? Are they indexed, too ?

Comment: In that case, you can simply store the data in a non-pair data structure. So you should use an array instead of a Map.

Comment: So, array contents are indexed and as fast as map queries ?

Comment: Yes, there are. You can use them without any problem.

Comment: Ok, that's clear now. Is there a method analogous to arrayContains but for maps to query documents that their map contains a certain key

Comment: Yes, there is. Assuming you have in your document a Map named `admins` which contains an element with the key `adminId` and the value `true`, you can use the following query: `db.collection("yourCollection").whereEqualTo("admins.adminId", true)`. You can also query using: `db.collection("yourCollection").whereEqualTo("admins.adminId", null)`, if those values are `null`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. Thanks for help